# How to call member functions from a class nested within a namespace?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to call a class member function that's nested within a namespace from a different file, but I don't know how.

For example:

How to call a class member function `someFunc()` that's located in code.h and nested within namespace "program" from main.cpp.

```
//code.h
#include <iostream>

namespace program
class test {
private:
    int x;
public:
    test()
    {
        test::x = 10;
    };

    someFunc()
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    };
};
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: please provide  a [mcve]. The code you posted has errors that are not related to your question

Comment: There's really no namespace "nesting" in the code you show, and it definitely won't build.

Comment: given you fix all the errors and you have an instance called `t`  it would be `t.someFunc();`, the question is unclear. I have the feeling you have some code that is not working, but you dont show it but instead posted code that has different errors

Comment: `test::x` is unnecessary, you are in class test already, so if you solely write `x = 10;` the correct variable would be found anyway. You'd need to qualify, though, if you wanted to refer to some equally named variable of a base class.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code

```
#include <iostream>

namespace program { // <-- braces missing

class test
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    test()
    {
        test::x = 10; // <-- test:: is unnecessary but no error
    };

    void someFunc() // <-- return type missing
    {
        std::cout << x << " "; // <-- namespace std missing
    };
};

} // <-- braces missing

int main() {
    program::test t;
    t.someFunc();
}
```